# getting undefined value in localstorage angularjs

Tags: angular-local-storage

In below **ExamppleController** function a value is entered into **message** variable local storage. For the first time value is getting stored but when entered again value is not getting stored. When **browser cache** is cleared then value is stored again and second time no value is getting stored.

**Mystorage.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ngStorage.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var example = angular.module("example", ["ngStorage"]);
            example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope,$rootScope,$window,$localStorage,$location) {     
            $scope.save = function() {
                $rootScope.newq=$scope.name;
                $scope.$apply();
                **$localStorage.message = $scope.name;**
                console.debug($localStorage.message);
                $window.location.href = 'nextstorage.html';
            }                           
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="example">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
            <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>               
            <br>
            {{data}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NextStorage.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ngStorage.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var example = angular.module("example", ["ngStorage"]);
            example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope,$window,$localStorage,$location) {              
                    $scope.data1 = $localStorage.message;               
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="example">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

        <span>{{data1}}</span>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing things the AngularJS way.  I think this is where the disconnect happens.

See the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ngStorage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var example = angular.module("example", ["ngStorage", "ui.router"]);
            example.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                .state('1', {
                    url: '/1',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/1.html',
                    controller: 'FirstController'
                })
                .state('2', {
                    url: '/2',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/2.html',
                    controller: 'SecondController'
                });
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/1');
            });
            example.controller("FirstController", function($scope,$localStorage,$location) {
                $scope.save = function() {
                    $localStorage.message = $scope.name;
                    $location.path("/2");
                }
            });
            example.controller("SecondController", function($scope,$localStorage,$location) {
                $scope.data1 = $localStorage.message;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="example">
        <div ui-view></div>

        <script id="templates/1.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
                <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
                <br>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script id="templates/2.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <div>
                <span>{{data1}}</span>
            </div>
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

You'll notice I'm using routes and navigating between them using the $location provider.  The $localStorage works fine when doing it this way.

Read up on the ui-router or ngRoute.

Regards,

Comment: in the routing localstorage.html will move to localstorage.html/2 ok but my scenario is different it need to change localstorage.html to next.html